# How to update NSResponder selector in swift 2.2

Tags: swift, selector, nsresponder

I am implementing a NSControlTextEditingDelegate protocol and I don't know which class/protocol i should match with e.g. commandSelector. #selector(WhichClass.moveUp(_:)) so that the equality will pass.

Currently everything is ok with swift 2.1:

```
func control(control: NSControl, textView: NSTextView, doCommandBySelector commandSelector: Selector) -> Bool {

    var goUp = false
    var goDown = false

        if (commandSelector == Selector("moveUp:") ||
        commandSelector == Selector("moveBackward:") ||
        commandSelector == Selector("moveUpAndModifySelection:") ||
        commandSelector == Selector("moveParagraphBackwardAndModifySelection:")
            )

        {
            goUp = true
        }
        if (commandSelector == Selector("moveDown:") ||
        commandSelector == Selector("moveForward:") ||
        commandSelector == Selector("moveDownAndModifySelection:") ||
        commandSelector == Selector("moveParagraphForwardAndModifySelection:")
            ) {
            goDown = true

        }
//...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (commandSelector == #selector(NSResponder.moveUp) ||
```

You can write it as the following if you prefer:

```
if (commandSelector == #selector(NSResponder.moveUp(_:)) ||
```

In fact, generated `Selector` instance from `#selector` does not contain the class info. So, you just find any class defining the same method with the same signature.

---

And if you cannot find any class, you can define it in your own protocol and use the protocol name.

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol {
    func moveUp(_:AnyObject)
    //...
}
```

And use it in `#selector`:

```
if (commandSelector == #selector(MyProtocol.moveUp(_:)) ||
```

---

The latter should be the last way, but it actually works.

Comment: Thanks for answer. So no need to worry about equality?

Comment: @MarekH, you can easily check it, `#selector(MyProtocol.moveUp(_:)) == #selector(NSResponder.moveUp)` returns true. Two selectors are equal when their Objective-C notation (like "moveUp:") are equal. Don't worry.

Comment: For anyone coming here in 2023 or later, the selector is now `NSStandardKeyBindingResponding.moveUp`